# File won't rename itself?

Tags: variables, time, batch-file, rename

I'm trying to teach my .bat file to rename itself to the current date each time it's clicked.

Can somebody tell me why it doesn't work?

```
@echo off
set timeme=%s%

RENAME %0 %timeme%.bat
```

Comment: I would say that the obvious lack of any AI in that code is the culprit :)

Comment: The renaming itself works for me. (I used an arbitrary string instead of `%s%`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can copy it to the new name and delete the old one as first statement in the new file.

Or you can create a seperate script that waits for the original file to unlock and then renames it. Call this script as the last statement in the original file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the file is locked while your script is be executed - you cannot rename it.  Same as if you had a document open in Word.  Best you can do is copy.

Comment: nope nevermind i got it ussing the %random% option. prefeurably though i would like a random alphanumrical

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, the renaming part works fine. You should keep in mind, though, that it also produces an error message, and your batch script is going to terminate immediately after renaming. So the `RENAME` command should be the last one in your script. (Still, if the name doesn't change after renaming, the script doesn't terminate either, and you might use that to your advantage somehow, but that's a different story.)

So if you have problems 'teaching' your batch script how to rename itself, I should presume it's got something to do with the `%s%` bit of your example. And because you've said you are trying to set the new name to the current date, then maybe that part is just what's causing the problem. Therefore I've decided to share my approach to this specific self-renaming with you.

Here's a working example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET timeme=%DATE:/=-%
SET timeme=%timeme: =-%
RENAME %0 %timeme%.bat
```

Here I am using the output of the `DATE` environment variable. The output of this variable is formatted according to the local settings. On my computer it is formatted as `ddd MM/dd/yyyy`, so `%DATE%` evaluates to something like `Fri 04/22/2011`.

You can see that I'm not simply using the output, but also processing it in some way. In fact, I am replacing `/` and  (the space) with `-` so I can use the result as a file name and do so without the need to enclose the name in double quotes. You may need to check your `%DATE%` output to see whether you need to substitute some other characters too.

But you might also like to use the output differently. For example, you could cut the year, the month, and the day out of the date string, concatenate the parts and use the resulting string as the new name. Here's an example of how it can be done (it arranges the parts in the format of `yyyyMMdd`):

```
SET timeme=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
```

Again, this expression is tuned to my date display format, so you may need to change all or some of the numbers to adapt it to your environment.

To get more information on substring extraction (as well as on substring substitution, like in my earlier script example), you can issue [**`HELP SET`**](http://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm) from the command prompt at any time.